# The preventDefault() isn't working, how can I make it so, that it works correctly?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The `preventDefault()` isn't working correctly. When I press the Login button, the page refresh's, but with the `preventDefault()` it shouldn't.

I tried it with `stopPropagation()`, but there was the same problem.

TypeScript:

```
loginUser(loginevent){
  loginevent.preventDefault()
  const target = loginevent.target
  const username = target.getElementById('username')
  const password = target.getElementById('pasword')
  console.log(username, password)
}
```

HTML:

```
  <form (submit)="loginUser($loginevent)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" id="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Passwort" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

The `loginevent.preventDefault()` should prevent the page from reloading it, when I press the Login button.

Comment: Have you tried both at the same time preventDefault + stopPropagation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(someForm)"?
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12757#issuecomment-268633198
https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Is there a reason for not using angular forms in the first place? I mean, you are using Angular, then why not actually use angular? ;)

Comment: it is in a Angular7 project, so I am using Angular. When I use preventDefault + stopPropagation it doesn't work too. and with (ngSubmit) I get the same Problem

Comment: Yes, but you are not using what angular has to offer! This would be a non-angular approach what you are doing now.

Comment: So, it should be something like this: (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginUser($loginevent)), but this is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to pass `$event` as an argument and not any other word. `$event` is a reserved keyword to get the event data.

Here's what the [**Angular Docs**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) say:

> The framework passes the event argument—represented by $event—to the handler method, and the method processes it:

Try this:

```
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" id="username">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Passwort" id="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should use what angular has to offer, either a template-driven or reactive form. We are coding with angular, then why not do it the angular way :)

Template driven:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser(f.value)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" name="username" ngModel>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Passwort" name="password" ngModel>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here you now pass the form value to your login, which contains your username and password:

```
loginUser(values){
  const username = values.username
  const password = values.password
  console.log(username, password)
}
```

With this, you don't even need to worry about `preventDefault()`

But I would also recommend the reactive way, read more about both template-driven and reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms